# How can I modify my .htaccess to create a custom URL from a submitted form?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, custom-wordpress-pages

When I submit a form then get this type of URL:
`http://localhost/c/?name1=5paisa&name2=abhipra-capital`
and I want this instead: `http://localhost/c/5paisa-vs-abhipra-capital`

This is my .htaccess code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    # Handle WordPress internal rewrites
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    # Redirect /name1-vs-name2 to index.php with query parameters
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)-vs-([^/]+)/?$ index.php?name1=$1&name2=$2 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

And I want to know why it's not working?

I want that when a user submits said form then the URL should look like this:
`http://localhost/c/5paisa-vs-abhipra-capital`

Comment: I am assuming that `/c/` is not an actually existing file or folder - so first of all you would need to place this _before_ the block that rewrites _all_ requests that do not map onto an existing folder or file to the index.php.

Comment: You tried to implement a rewrite _from_ `/c/5paisa-vs-abhipra-capital` to `index.php?name1=$1&name2=$2` - but that makes little sense, because the _requested_ URL is not the fancy one you want, but `/c/?name1=5paisa&name2=abhipra-capital`. So you would need to make an external redirect _from_ `/c/?name1=5paisa&name2=abhipra-capital` to `/c/5paisa-vs-abhipra-capital` first of all.

Comment: The other alternative would be to intercept the form submission on the client side, then _create_ the URL format you want out of the form field values, and assign that URL to `location.href`. That would eliminate the need for that first initial redirect _to_ the fancy URL format.